# Physical Device: Infinite hang : Trying to initialize the debugger

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

**Device : ZTE Z716BLB01  / Android 5.1.1**

We have added the device on our testing suite/environment to trace/debug end-user run-time issues but the debugger never attaches to the device.

**Note**: **Android Studio does connect and debug properly to the same device**

Xamarin Studio "Application output" of a non-modified template created Android app:

```
Forwarding debugger port 8866
Detecting existing process
> am start -n "com.sushihangover.ztetestdebugging/md5c4a2c575ff4d573ba8e8bab7833a0b82.MainActivity"
> Starting: Intent { cmp=com.sushihangover.ztetestdebugging/md5c4a2c575ff4d573ba8e8bab7833a0b82.MainActivity }

[art] Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
[monodroid] Using override path: /data/data/com.sushihangover.ztetestdebugging/files/.__override__
[monodroid] Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.sushihangover.ztetestdebugging/files/.__override__
[monodroid] Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.sushihangover.ztetestdebugging/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[monodroid] Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.sushihangover.ztetestdebugging/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[monodroid] Trying to load sgen from: /data/app/com.sushihangover.ztetestdebugging-1/lib/arm/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[monodroid] Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.sushihangover.ztetestdebugging/files/.__override__/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
[monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8866,server=y,embedding=1
```

Debugger never connects and the application on the device that is launched only displays a blank screen/activity.

I added this as a Xamarin bug but have heard nothing back in 2 weeks so I posting here to see if anyone has a solution to this.

Ref: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42375

Note: The issue was confirmed by Xaramin, but there is not solution to the issue.

#### Update: 05/07/2018

I am working with another client that is developing Android One devices ((O & P API levels / non-US market) and we are experiencing this same condition on all the prototypes when using `Xamarin.Android` but as with the original issue, Android Studio has no problems debugging Java/JNI applications on these devices (which is using a host->device debug connection vs. Mono's "reverse" device->host debug connection)

Comment: Can you connect to the device via adb?

Comment: The phone have a custom rom? Did you tried flashing it to test other rom?

Comment: Ok, I understand it, so since you are trying to solve this from a long time, I suggest you to try another rom and then try to put the stock rom again. Only to see if it was software related.

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug! I am going to look into it further and will update.